# Mapping one entity in Hibernate from two tables (in postgreSQL) with different functionality

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, intellij-idea

I currently have an entity mapped for one table (controller allows to view, filter, edit, etc) which is used for a website. There is a view in the database that shows data from that table and another one which is almost identical (difference being it has one less field and it should not be edited). It is required from me to map an entity for that view, so that I can show it (meaning both of those tables), but add new data/edit preexisting data only in the first one. I have very little experience in Hibernate, so it seems almost like the solution is close and easier to implement than it seems. Maybe there is a way to get data from the view, but when editing is involved, use original entity? Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: You can use `SecondaryTable` annotation to map two tables to one entity. Writing is enabled.